# Can a Bluetooth device (as client) connect to multiple Bluetooth devices?

Tags: c++, bluetooth

I'm little confused about Bluetooth, I know there is a difference between server and client, my main question is if I can connect for example my computer Bluetooth device as client to multiple Bluetooth devices. 
**Context:** I have two Arduinos UNO both with Bluetooth module and I want to connect my computer to both of them, should my computer act as server? If yes is there a way to establish connection from the Arduino to my computer? Or should my computer act as client and connect to both Arduinos? 
**PD:** I'm using Bluez library with C++

Comment: The Arduino Bluetooth module acts as a server. To connect the PC to multiple Arduinos, you need to create multiple client connects and connect each one to a separate Arduino.

Comment: So HC-05 and HC-06 both act as servers? As far as I know HC-06 is slave and HC-05 is master. I got an HC-06, so my computer can connect as client to both Arduinos?